# Can I create a constructable SimpleNamespace in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to construct an `twoNum` dynamically - I've got the constants built, and the lambda works, but I'm not sure how to make `ns` constructible.

```
class twoNum:
    a = 1
    b = 2

    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b


ns = types.SimpleNamespace()
setattr(ns,'a',1)
setattr(ns,'b',2)
setattr(ns,'c',lambda : self.a + self.b)
```

When I do:

```
r = ns()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object is not callable
```

Comment: If you want to create a costume module you need to put it in your python directory

Comment: You need to call `r=ns()` from outside the file you define it on! @Carbon

Comment: What do you expect `ns()` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate `ns` outside the python script you defined it on. So if your `script.py` has the following code in it

```
import types

class twoNum:
    a = 1
    b = 2

    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b


ns = types.SimpleNamespace()
setattr(ns,'a',1)
setattr(ns,'b',2)
setattr(ns,'c',lambda : self.a + self.b)
```

Then the following will work .

```
In [1]: from script import ns                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: ns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[2]: namespace(a=1, b=2, c=<function <lambda> at 0x110dde6a8>)

In [3]: ns.a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: ns.b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[4]: 2
```

Also your definition of function c is incorrect, you don't have a and b as class attributes, so you cannot do `self.a` or `self.b`, you can try as follows

```
def c(self):
    return a + b
```

Which can then be run as follows

```
In [5]: ns.c(5,6)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[5]: 11
```